# Nested Tabs in October CMS Backend

Tags: nested, octobercms, octobercms-backend

How you can create nested tabs in the backend? My task: create two new tabs within one tab. Let's say there are three tabs "Abc", "Def", and "Hig" with different fields inside. So, I need to create two new tabs (like the second level) inside the "Def" tab. How to do it? I didn't find a solution in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach would be to use the `nestedForm` widget. Check out the documentation here: https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-nestedform